# Create ActiveRecord migration then edit in one step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, migration

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
script/generate migration my_new_migration
```

.. then select & copy the generated filename, then paste it into vi to actually write the migration.

Is there any way to do this in one step?  i.e. when the script/generate migration runs, it creates the file the automatically opens that file in an editor?

(I'm working in an SSH terminal window on linux..)

Comment: Can't you just create a bash script that does this?

Comment: Perhaps, but not exactly sure how?  (I'm relatively new to this environment..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.    However, I actually just stumbled upon this:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567

Pretty sweet, as it lets you do

```
> :Rscript generate migration my_migration
```

.. from inside VIM, and it will automatically generate the migration then load it up in the editor for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit generator script. When file is generated than exec $EDITOR [new_file] or something like that?